# trying to scrape all facebook links from a web page

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to scrape the page for links from Facebook. However, I get a blank page, without any error message.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function getFacebook($html) {

    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('~^https?://(?:www\.)?facebook.com/(.+)/?$~', $html, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches);

    }
}

$html = file_get_contents('http://curvywriter.info/contact-me/');

getFacebook($html);
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: getting a blank page.. no output..

Comment: That means your match fails. Try `preg_match_all`, for once, and ditch the `^` and `$` from your pattern.

Comment: Also, please include those details in your question next time. What you've tried, what went wrong, what errors you're getting, etc. With [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: is that the reason i got -1 on this one. please notethat, i did say i wasnot getting any output.

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative (and more robust) would be to use DOMDocument and DOMXPath:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function getFacebook($html) {

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    $query = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $result = $query->evaluate("(//a|//A)[contains(@href, 'facebook.com')]");

    $return = array();

    foreach ($result as $element) {
        /** @var $element DOMElement */
        $return[] = $element->getAttribute('href');
    }

    return $return;

}

$html = file_get_contents('http://curvywriter.info/contact-me/');

var_dump(getFacebook($html));
```

---

For your specific problem, however, I did the following things:

- Change `preg_match` to `preg_match_all`, in order to not stop after the first finding.
- Removed the `^` (start) and `$` (end) characters from the pattern. Your links will appear in the middle of the document, not in the beginning or end (definitely not both!)

So the corrected code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function getFacebook($html) {

    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match_all('~https?://(?:www\.)?facebook.com/(.+)/?~', $html, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches);

    }
}

$html = file_get_contents('http://curvywriter.info/contact-me/');

getFacebook($html);
```

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction on how i can clean the codes and remove the extra tags such as 'taget=blank' and the anchor text. I just want the facebook urls.